# Baixando dados da internet do site BovespaBMF pelo R

Tags: r

Estou precisando dos dados desse site aqui da Bovespa:

```
http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/historico/mercado-a-vista/series-historicas/
```

Os dados que eu quero é das ações de 2017 e 2018. Para isso preciso clicar na opção `Séries Anuais (todos os dias úteis do ano escolhido)` passar pelo teste da imagem e aí fazer o download do arquivo.

O download vem no formato .Zip

Eu preciso abri-lo e fazer todas as modificações para leva-lo ao excel.

E então puxar pelo R.

Como faço para aprender a puxar dados pelo R nesse tipo de situação?

Obrigada

Comment: Oi Laura, essa pergunta é muito complexa para ser respondida por aqui. Eu acho que esse material pode ser útil para você começar: https://www.curso-r.com/material/webscraping/

Comment: Muito obrigada Daniel.